How can I disable touchpad multi-finger swipe gestures for “back navigation” in Flutter Web?
I am building a Flutter Web application, and I want to prevent the browser’s default behavior where swiping right with two or more fingers on a touchpad triggers the “go back to the previous page” action.
is it possible to disable this?
here is a small video of the issue if the question is not clear:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6kjKisws8o
I didnt find any stack overflows, chatgpt/claude didnt know either.
didnt see any articles on this matter aswell

I know that disabling this feature is possible because when I am in a google sheet I can slide to the left with two fingers and nothing happens


This is built-in browser behavior and can't be disabled by a web app. Instead, you could catch the back nav request and confirm before navigating away.

@Lee3 I dont think so because in a google sheets it's 100% disabled. I can slide to the left with two fingers all day and nothing will happen. but thank you for commenting

I have tested in javascript now. By listening for wheel events and returning false or calling event.preventDefault(), you can prevent scroll events from bubbling up to the browser. This will prevent the nav behavior. So you are correct, this can be disabled, not sure of the best way to do so in Flutter. You may be able to fake infinite scroll in the widget to get around this, but your best bet is probably to use the js package or js_interop to selectively intercept scroll events via javascript.
